# Trigger ./gradlew test when files have changed

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am building a Spring Boot REST API application and using Kotlin as the language.
For the development I am using IntellJ as the IDE.

The project structure looks as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to watch changes in the folder `src` to trigger the gradle task `./gradlew test` after files have been changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Gradle's [support for continuous builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:continuous_build):

```
./gradlew test --continuous
```

This will cause Gradle to watch the filesystem for changes and execute the `test` task and any tasks upon which it depends whenever a change is detected.

Answer (score 4):

You can right click the gradle task and set it to be done e.g. after each build.

[image]